# How exactly does the pull-back motor (12787) work?

Tags: piece-information, technic

I've got the [42034 Quad](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=42034-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ii%22:1%7D) for my birthday and it's been really fun to play with technic after so many years.

I am very curious about one thing, though - how does the [pull-back motor (12787)](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=12787c01&idColor=85#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:85,%22ii%22:1%7D) work and look internally? I'd unscrew mine but I am afraid I'd damage it.

I am guessing it probably uses some kind of spring and/or rubber bands to build the pressure but I'd love to know it's internals precisely.

Answer (score 7):

Another type of pullback motor has a detailed structural disassembly here: [Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9xe6.jpg).

I think your motor should work mostly the same way, but I wasn't able to source such internal pictures.

---

### LEGO Micro Pull-back Motor Reassembly

[image]

Micro Pull-back Motor Parts

Gear A: Pin shaped like 'E' for attachment to Spring on Chassis
Gear B: Smallest (of 2) gear with a pin
Gear C: Largest gear with 2 levels, smaller gear at the bottom, larger gear on top, with teeth for meshing with Axle F
Gear D: Smallest (of 2) gear with a hole
Gear E: Medium gear with 2 levels
Axle Assembly F
Gear Assembly G

Not shown: 5 X-head screws
Note: Gear A may be detached from Spring. 
I attached it such that it won't fall out when flipped upside down.

[image]

Install Gear B
Place Gear B with pin downwards into slot in Gear Assembly G

[image]

Install Gear C.
Place Gear C into the hole in Gear Assembly G.
The larger gear is on top.
Gear C will cover Gear B and mesh with it 
(though Gear B has some play since it is in a slot)

[image]

Install Gear E.
Place Gear E into the small depression in Gear Assembly G.
The larger gear is at the bottom, and will slide under Gear C.
There is a pin facing up. Gear E will mesh with Gear B.

[image]

Attach Gear D to the Axle Assembly F.
Gear D has a small hole which fits on the pin on Axle Assembly F.

[image]

Attach the Axle Assembly F to the Gear Assembly Cover G.
Flip the Axle over. 
Gear D should stay attached to the Axle Assembly.
Align the Axle Assembly and snap down on the protruding pin on the Gear Assembly.
Pinch the two parts (F & G) together at the lower section using thumb and index finger, and try to spin the axle. 
The gears should only rotate when the axle is spun in one direction, and not the other.

[image]

Reattach the Gear Assembly G to the Chassis.
This step is tricky. 
You will need to pinch the Gear Assembly to keep parts in place,
then place the Chassis on top of the Gear Assembly G, and move it around
until Gear A connects with the correct hole and mesh with the other gears.
Then, holding everything tightly, flip it over, and start installing and tightening the screws in a diagonal pattern.
Don't over tighten the screws, you should install at least 3 screws first (one on top, two at the bottom), and test that the spring is engaged with Gear A and you get a pull back action when the wheels are turned.
After that, install the rest of the screws and tighten all of them.

[image]

The pull back action works, but I can't figure out how to fix the torque on the spring. 
So the car is no longer a race car but a jalopy!

Comment: The Picasa album you referenced appears to be a dead link.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, it seems Picasa as a service has been retired. I have found the images and reuploaded them to Imgur, hopefully that will not go away soon :)

Comment: The imgur link is now also dead, can you upload them again?

Comment: @Ralph Strange, I'm still seeing all of the pictures by clicking on the link.

Comment: My mistake, works in Chrome, not in my Firefox, must be something my end, proxy maybe

Comment: @Ralph No problem, glad that got sorted out :)

Comment: And now it's broken **AGAIN**.

Comment: @mindstormsboi It seems to work for me, are you sure it's broken from your perspective?

Comment: @zovits Yes, it's giving the 404 page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wXF.jpg Why don't you go click the "ask question" button and upload the photo using the markdown imgur uploader? I'm thinking that any other method can cause it to not work.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I have embedded the images in the post to take advantage of the SE-Imgur collaboration.